# Relation_aggregate in QGIS in M:N relationship

Tags: many-to-many, expression, calculated-columns, qgis

I have table1 Troncon and table2 Ligne_offre who are related through a 3rd Intermediate table link_troncon_ligne_offre, because its a M to N relationship. In the table 1, I have a field niveau_offre. In the intermediate table I have also the field niveau_offre. So when I stablish a relations between one entity from table1 and one or many entities from table2, I need that in the intermediate table the field niveau_offre is populated with information from table1 niveau_offre.

I tried in the intermediate table form with the default value and the following expression:

`relation_aggregate('troncon_link_ligne_offre', 'niveau_offre', "objectid_troncon" = attribute($currentfeature, 'objectid_troncon'))`

but I have this error: Evaluation error: Impossible to find a link with the id 'troncon_link_ligne_offre'.

The relations are stablished in the QGIS projet throught the field objectid_troncon.

Any idea how to get the values from table1 in the intermediate table when we made relations?